# The behaviour of a bounded function $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be bounded. I want to show that
$$
\limsup_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} < \infty \tag{1}
$$
$$
\iff
$$
$$
\sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{ 0 \} } \frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} < \infty, \tag{2}
$$
and that $(1)$ or $(2)$ imply
$$
\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0} f ( x ) = 0. \tag{3}
$$

---

$(2)$ means that there is some $C > 0$ such that
$$
\frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} \leq C \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d \setminus \{ 0 \},
$$
hence
$$
\limsup_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} \leq C,
$$
so $(2) \Rightarrow (1)$.
But how can one obtain the converse direction in a rigorous way, as well as $(3)$? I guess somehow the boundedness of $f$ should be used.

---

Following @GregMartin's hint:

$(1)$ means that there is some $1 > \varepsilon > 0$ and $C_1 > 0$ such that
$$
\frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} \leq C_1 \quad \forall \ 0 < |x| < \varepsilon. \tag{4}
$$
Otherwise, if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and $C > 0$ there is some $0 < |x_0| < \varepsilon$ such that
$$
\frac{|f(x_0) - x_0|}{|x_0|^2} > C
$$
then also
$$
\limsup_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} \geq C \quad \forall C > 0,
$$
contradiciting $(1)$. We also see that $\forall x : |x| \geq 1$
$$
\frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2} \leq \frac{|f(x)| + |x|}{|x|^2} = \frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^2}+\frac{1}{|x|} \leq |f(x)| + 1 \leq C_2
$$
for some $C_2 > 0$, as $f$ is bounded. Obviously, $|f(x)-x|/|x|^2$ is also bounded for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^d, \varepsilon \leq |x| < 1$ by some $C_3 > 0$. We therefore get $(2)$. To see that $(1)$ implies $(3)$, note that
$$
|f(x) - x| \leq C_1 |x|^2 \quad \forall x \in B_{ \varepsilon } ( 0 ) \setminus \{ 0 \},
$$
according to $(4)$ and so
$$
|f(x)| \leq |f (x) - x | + |x| \leq C_1 |x|^2+|x|,
$$
which implies $(3)$.

Comment: Hint for (1) implies (2): if $f$ is bounded, or even if $|f(x)| \le 100|x|^2$, then $$\sup_{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d ,\, |x|\ge1 } \frac{|f(x) - x|}{|x|^2}$$ is automatically bounded. Hint for (1) implies (3): (1) implies that there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(x)-x| < C|x|^2$ when $x$ is sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks for the hint. Could you please take a look at my edited post to see whether the arguments can be improved?

Comment: Pretty good job! Two comments. First, your "otherwise" argument is currently phrased in the form "for every $\varepsilon$ there exists $x_0$ such that for every $C$"; notice that this order of quantifiers would allow $x_0$ to depend on $\varepsilon$ but not on $C$, which isn't what we want (and also isn't true). It should be phrased in the form "for every $\varepsilon$ and for every $C$ there exists $x_0$ such that", which is the appropriate hypothetical negation of (1).

Comment: Second, any time we say "obviously", we should cross out "obviously" and prove the "obvious" thing :) In this case, there's no need for separate arguments for $|x|\ge1$ and $\varepsilon \le |x| \le 1$; just do the first argument with $1$ replaced by $\varepsilon$ in the first place.